# How to extend existing Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Currently I have a Spring Web Application built using Spring Boot that exposes some restful endpoints. I need to be able to extend its functionality without rebuilding the entire project.

I created a new Maven project and set the only dependency to my main Spring Boot project. My new project only has two files: it has an entity class and a repository interface for the new entity annotated with @RepositoryRestResource.

These new classes are in the same packages as similar pieces of the parent project.

Is there a way I can restart the existing application and have it include the classes in the external jar? I want to to scan these two classes and treat them as they were part of the original project.

The point of this is to be able to add new tables/entities/endpoints without having to change the base project in case the new entity does not exist in a deployment.

Comment: Haven't tried it with Spring Boot, but this looks like a good candidate for [shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which you can use to build a new jar from the old jar plus the new classes. To work, it would require that Boot is scanning your annotated classes and not just recording a fixed list of references.  But this is Spring, so I guess that it'll be doing the right thing.

Comment: Take a look at the WAR Overlay Method done by CAS https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Best+Practice+-+Setting+Up+CAS+Locally+using+the+Maven+WAR+Overlay+Method